# I want read balance of charge inside my transportaion DESFire card. is it possible?How can read?(on android)

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am new by RFID and NFC and DESfire cards. I already read UID from desfire tag. Bellow code gives UID from defire tags.

UID is in text3, but only first 7th byte from it.

```
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

            TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "discovered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Falied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            byte[] tagResponse = null;
            byte[] tagResponse1 = null;
            byte[] tagResponse2 = null;

           Tag desfire = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            isodep = IsoDep.get(desfire);

            try {
                isodep.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

           //byte[] test = new byte[] { (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0x00 };
           byte[] test=new byte[]{(byte)0x60};
           byte[] test1=new byte[]{(byte)(0xAF)};
         //  byte[] test2=new byte[]{(byte)(90AF000000)};


            try {

                tagResponse = isodep.transceive(test);
                tagResponse1 = isodep.transceive(test1);
                tagResponse2 = isodep.transceive(test1);

                text1.setText(bytesToHex(tagResponse));
                text2.setText(bytesToHex(tagResponse1));
                text3.setText(bytesToHex(tagResponse2));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            try {
                isodep.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

The only tag available in my hand for my tests is a transportation card. I now want read balance of charge inside my transportaion card. is it possible?( I have a tablet which supports nfc.) If it is possible how i must do it?please give me some regards or code example. I am very new by DESFire reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not possible to read the balance out of transportation cards as it is saved in a locked card sector.
You would need to know the key and number of the sector used to be able to read (and possibly alter) the information.

You may try to use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo to identify the sector. However without the key, you cannot read the stored data.